# Using minitest methods in capybara ruby implementation?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

Im very new at ruby coding and I always use capybara native methods.
Now, I need to use some assert methods for unit testing only available in rspec matchers or minitest. Rspec was discarded because some gem trouble in system machine...so.....minitest is the choice.

My question is:

Can only access to minitest methods using class like this? (see in documentation)

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class myTest < Minitest::Test
```

If I already have my class like this:

```
class myTest < BasePageExample

def method1()
  "needed assert_equal(.............)"
end
end
```

How can I import minitest for my existant class and use assert_equal method???

Thanks!!!

Comment: what is `BasePageExample`, can you show the code?

Comment: Is a page object that brings support methods to this class by inheritance

Comment: Half blind guessing, you should be able to 'include Minitest::Assertions' into your class. It's a module defined here: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb

Depending on your needs you might want to do this already in BasePageExample.

Comment: with this include: undefined method `assertions' for #<MyTest>... something wrong with the imports? 
require "minitest/autorun"
include Minitest::Assertions

Comment: To include Minitest::Assertions you need to provide your own `assertions` accessor as documented here - https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L12 .  Note, when you start moving away from the Capybara provided assertions, in tests using Capybara, you lose the waiting/retrying behavior which can lead to flaky tests.  What type of thing do you need to `assert_equal` on?

Comment: I have read this documentation, but cant find what is the assertions accesor to bring into my code. In some of my capybara tests, i need to do an assertion between to strings recovered from input fields on screen, so I need some methods to assert items like it was an unitary test. Waiting times and synchronization wouldnt be an issue in this case (for now...)